# How can I get file name from hib

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hipi

I am using hipi mapreduce to process image. During mapreduce process, i cannot find the original file name in the imageheader.

In imageheader of hipi, can i add any meta data to identify the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could append the filename to EXIF by any external tools such as EXIFTool. You can set the Model Name to the file name. In the HIPI Mapreduce, you could get the information.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the file name of the image from .getMetaData(key) method of FloatImage.
As an example during mapreduce process:

```
 public void map(HipiImageHeader key, FloatImage value, Context context) 
        throws IOException, InterruptedException {
......
    String filename =  value.getMetaData("filename");
    System.out.println("filename:="+filename);
}
```

And the outpout will be:
filename:=myImage.jpeg